# Write code on javascript to jquery like code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Now i'm using dtree.js for my treeview on my page, but it's showing on the top (i'm using rails asset pipeline, and writed this code in other js file (not in haml))...
But it's appending to document, but i need to some class or id, moreover, in jquery look-like code in some cases i must hide all this tree, i don't know how to do this in siple js, only on jquery. But this is very good tree for my app, could'not change it.
Or is it any good tree with same way of adding data (for example: id, par id, link, name) ? Without any json-look like code etc...

```
amiscompany = new dTree('amiscompany');
amiscompany.add(10001,-1,'<a style="text-decoration:underline;" onclick="fade();" rel="nofollow" href="/search_trees/category/cat=">Каталог запчастей</a>');
amiscompany.add(10441,10001,'Внутренняя отделка',"/search_trees/category/cat=10441?SEL=1");
amiscompany.add(12797,10441,'Багажник / помещение для груза',"/search_trees/category/cat=12797?SEL=2");
amiscompany.add(10830,10441,'Комплектующие',"/search_trees/category/cat=10830?SEL=3");
.....
document.write(amiscompany);
amiscompany.openTo(0, true);
```

Comment: It is hard to understand your question.  Can you add an example of what you want your output to look like?  Can you add more details?

Comment: @Brad this code is in simple javascript, i want to port it on jquery language (know that is js too)... So after that i will able to do anything with that code: show where i need, hide etc

Comment: If you want that code to be jQuery, you need to rewrite the dTree to accept jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *best* way to write your tree is to generate a `<ul>` and `<li>` directly in whatever server-side language you are using.  This makes your web site fully visible to Google.

You *can* do things like you want with the `dTree` library.  I played with it once, but found it too hard to control to my liking.

I know you said you didn't want something that looked like `JSON` but you didn't explain why.  If you are going to write your own function to do things, `JSON` really is the cleanest way and you can have it generate and build your list.  Using `localStorage` you can even remember which tree items were expanded or closed and render the tree in the same shape from page to page.

Comment: i know, but in json i must config rails json output, then port it in for example jqtree... my code have about 1000 items (nodes), so it's not so easy...